# Working with ambiguous AddGeometryColumn functions

Tags: spatial-database, postgis-2.0

I'm using PostGIS to add geometry columns to tables, but keep receiving the error:

```
ERROR: function addgeometrycolumn(character varying, character varying, integer, character varying, integer) is not unique
SQL state: 42725
Hint: Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

The statement I am trying to call is:

SELECT addGeometryColumn('schema', 'table', 'geom', 3857, 'POINT', 2);

I have tried type-casting each argument but I received the same message. I have also removed and re-installed the postgis extension, which made no difference.

I have used this function countless times before and am somewhat puzzled as to why it isn't working all of a sudden. I have also tried a few other postgis functions which gave me similar errors.

I am considering reinstalling postgresql/postgis but I will have to spend time reconfiguring the set-up so I am hoping there is an easier way to fix/get around this.

Does anybody have any advice as to what may be causing this?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12331981/error-function-addgeometrycolumn-is-not-unique